# Finding Polar Area Problem

Tags: calculus

So I've been staring at this problem for about half an hour because I cannot for the life of me understand what exactly I did wrong. I took a picture because with my stress level it would take me about 25 minutes of angry typing to type up everything using the html tags and all of that.

[image]

Comment: weird how the night I've been the most stressed in is the same night it's taken the longest for someone to answer. I give up

Comment: $$\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\cos2xdx=\int_0^{\frac\pi4}\cos2xdx+ \int_{\frac\pi4}^{\frac\pi2}\cos2xdx$$ >observe that the last integral is $<0$ But the area being positive, we need to consider the absolute value

Comment: Why are you integrating from 0 to pi/4 and then again from pi/4 to pi/2? I'm trying to find the area under the curve from 0 to pi/2 and multiplying it by 4 to find the total area...should integrating from 0 to pi/2 give me what I'm looking for? @labbhattacharjee

Comment: $\int_a^bf(x)dx=\int_a^cf(x)dx+\int_c^bf(x)dx$ where $a<c<b$  and $\int_a^cf(x)dx$ implies the area under $f(x)$ between $a,c$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your bounds. Consider the graph of $r^2 = 11 \cos(2\theta)$. We start at the point $(0,\sqrt{11})$. Now for what (smallest positive) value of $\theta$ will $r=0$ so that the curve reaches the origin? Well since $\cos(\pi/2)=0$, this will occur at the point $(\pi/4, 0)$. So the integral you are looking for is:
$$
4 \cdot  \left[ \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\pi/4} 11\cos(2\theta) ~d\theta \right] = 22\left[ \frac{1}{2}\sin{2\theta} \right]_0^{\pi/4} = 11[\sin\tfrac{\pi}{2}- \sin 0] = 11
$$